# get data from multiple tables in MySQL with different where conditions

Tags: php, mysql, join

i searched alot but could't find solution.

**problem**

i have 3 tables. **lessons**,**progress** and **courses**
and i am joining like this.

```
 SELECT c.course_id
    , l.topic
    , l.id
    , l.vid_duration
    , p.* 
 FROM courses c 
 LEFT 
 JOIN lessons l 
 ON l.course_id = c.course_id  
 LEFT 
 JOIN progress sp 
 ON l.id = p.lesson_id 
 WHERE c.slug = :course 
 and p.user_id = :userid
```

I want data from all tables.

It's working fine when both **Where** conditions are true, but not on false.

So, I want data form **lessons** and empty colunm from **progress** if condition **p.user_id = :userid** was false.

I hope you understand my problem.

Comment: If the intention is to `LEFT JOIN' a given table, then the conditions on that table have to go in the JOIN clause, not WHERE

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @coyeb60297 the WHERE is an extra condition

Comment: @B001ᛦ I don't know what that means.

Comment: @user16577935 can you tell me how to  **go in the JOIN clause, not WHERE**

Comment: @coyeb60297 can you explain, please?

Comment: try to use OR instead of AND and i think you get what you required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the user check in the join, not in the where condition
like so:

```
SELECT c.course_id,l.topic,l.id,l.vid_duration,p.* 
FROM courses c 
LEFT JOIN lessons l ON l.course_id=c.course_id  
LEFT JOIN progress p ON l.id = p.lesson_id and p.user_id = :userid
WHERE c.slug = :course
```

The reason for doing this is that JOINS use the "left join" (which is implicitly an outer join". This type of join means that if the condition works, return all the column data for that table for that row.. if the whole condition does not work, it will return all the data for tables mentioned previously, but for the table mentioned in the row, it'll return NULLS for all those columns.

I apologize for that description, as it's hard to put into words exactly how a complex outer (or left) join works without getting wordy.