# Combine Two Multidimensional Arrays on matching key values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-combine

**Problem**

i have two multidimensional arrays that look like this,

**1st Array**

```
array(
      [0] => Array
        (
        [course_id] => 10
        [topic] => Booda-hood, advice and an important pit.
        [lesson_id] => 10
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [course_id] => 10
        [topic] => new topic
        [lesson_id] => 11
    )
```

)

**2nd array**

```
  Array
    (
    [0] => Array
      (
        [id] => 10
        [description] => Lorem Ipsum is blablabla
        [course_title] => Lorem Ipsum is 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 11
        [description] => Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of 
        [course_title] => Lorem Ipsum 
    )
```

)

I want to combine both arrays like this **if($1st[0]['lesson_id'] == $2nd[0]['id'])**

**3rd array**

```
      array(
          [0] => Array
          (
           [course_id] => 10
           [topic] => Booda-hood, advice and an important pit.
           [lesson_id] => 10
           [id] => 10
           [description] => Lorem Ipsum is blablabla
           [course_title] => Lorem Ipsum is 
       )

[1] => Array
    (
        [course_id] => 10
        [topic] => new topic
        [lesson_id] => 11
        [id] => 11
        [description] => Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of 
        [course_title] => Lorem Ipsum
    )
```

)

I hope I explain everything!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show the code please.

Comment: Create a [mcve] of what you tried

Comment: @unclexo  I want to join the array on matching keys, basically, the first array is the progress of students and the second one is the course lessons so I want to check the progress of students on basics of the lesson to show the student. if student have any progress in lesson then show else nothing will happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
// Your array
$arr1 = [
  [
  'course_id' => 10,
  'topic' => 'Booda-hood, advice and an important pit.',
  'lesson_id' => 10
  ],
  [
  'course_id' => 10,
  'topic' => 'Booda-hood, advice and an important pit.',
  'lesson_id' => 11
  ]
];

$arr2 = [
  [
  'id' => 10,
  'description' => '10 Lorem Ipsum is blablabla',
  'course_title' => '10 Lorem Ipsum is blablabla'
  ],
  [
  'id' => 11,
  'description' => '11 Lorem Ipsum is blablabla',
  'course_title' => '11 Lorem Ipsum is blablabla'
  ]
];
 
// Combining arrays implementation 

foreach ( $arr2 as $k=>$v )
{
  // rename array2 `id` to `lesson_id`
  $arr2[$k]['lesson_id'] = $arr2[$k] ['id'];
  unset($arr2[$k]['id']);
}

// array_replace_recursive — Replaces elements from passed arrays into the first array recursively   
print_r(array_replace_recursive($arr1, $arr2));
?>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[
  {
    "course_id": 10,
    "topic": "Booda-hood, advice and an important pit.",
    "lesson_id": 10,
    "description": "10 Lorem Ipsum is blablabla",
    "course_title": "10 Lorem Ipsum is blablabla"
  },
  {
    "course_id": 10,
    "topic": "Booda-hood, advice and an important pit.",
    "lesson_id": 11,
    "description": "11 Lorem Ipsum is blablabla",
    "course_title": "11 Lorem Ipsum is blablabla"
  }
]
```

Hope this helps!

Ref - [array_replace_recursive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php)

Answer (score 0):

This solution will work for you--

```
$a = [
            [
                'course_id' => 10,
                'topic' => 'Booda-hood, advice and an important pit',
                'lesson_id' => 10,
            ],
            [
                'course_id' => 10,
                'topic' => 'new topic',
                'lesson_id' => 11,
            ]
        ];

        $b = [
            [
                'id' => 10,
                'description' => 'Lorem Ipsum is blablabla',
                'course_title' => 'Lorem Ipsum is',
            ],
            [
                'id' => 11,
                'description' => 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of',
                'course_title' => 'Lorem Ipsum',
            ]
        ];

        $a3 = [];
        foreach ($a as $key => $a1) {
            $search = $this->searchValueInArray($a1['lesson_id'], $b);
            if ($search != null) {
                $a3[] = array_merge($a1, $search);
            } else {
                $a3[] = $a1;
            }
        }
        print_r($a3);

function searchValueInArray($value, $array) {
        foreach ($array as $arr) {
            if ($arr['id'] == $value) {
                return $arr;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: that's giving me Fatal error **foreach() argument must be of type array|object, string given**  for the  **searchValueInArray** method you used

Comment: please check the $b (second array) must be an array

Comment: the mistake was **$this->searchValueInArray($a1['lesson_id'], $b);** it should be like this **$this->searchValueInArray($b,$a1['lesson_id']);**

Comment: your answer also gives an empty array when one of the arrays is empty

Comment: yes, you might need to add checks, I did not add checks wherever required

Comment: and if second array is empty then that would not returned empty

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Thanks for your time, Can you Answer this [get-data-from-multiple-tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68653597/get-data-from-multiple-tables-in-mysql-with-different-where-conditions?noredirect=1#comment121330679_68653597)? that is a part of this question.